# Проблема с возвратом значений из контекста Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Использую `Entity Framework` для доступа к данным. Есть класс контекста:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public string cs;
    public Context(string connection_string)
    {
        Database.Connection.ConnectionString = connection_string;
        cs = connection_string;
    }
    public DbSet<Customers> cust { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Orders> ord { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cars_In_Stock_Table> cars { get; set; }
}
```

Пытаюсь получить данные:

```
public IEnumerable<Cars_In_Stock_Table> GetAllCars()
    {
        return context.cars;
    }
```

Visual Studio относительно `context.cars` выдаёт:

> Неявное преобразование ...DbSet<...> в ...IEnumerable<...> невозможно

Видел примеры, где такой подход работает. Можно использовать `ToList()`, но хотелось бы разобраться в чём причина. Может ли это быть связано с версией `Entity Framework`?

Comment: а где context.cars.Load() ? и почему не юзаете потом context.cars.Local?

Comment: Зачем это нужно?

Comment: приведите полностью код ошибки и версию EF. в 6.0 студия на ваш код молчит.

Answer (score 2):

Метод должен возвращать `IEnumerable<Cars_In_Stock_Table>`, а Вы ему `DbSet` толкаете... Соответственно неявно преобразовать один тип к другому тут нельзя. Можно попробовать так:

```
public IEnumerable<Cars_In_Stock_Table> GetAllCars()
{
    return context.cars.AsEnumerable(); // или ToList();
}
```

Или так:

```
public IQueryable<Cars_In_Stock_Table> GetAllCars()
{
    return context.cars;
}
```

Еще, по поводу именования полей класса, советую ознакомиться с данной статьей: [Соглашения о написании кода на C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff926074.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Это не связано с версией фреймворка, это связано только с тем, что DbSet это не IEnumerable, хотя его базовый класс DbQuery применяет в том числе этот интерфейс. Но если вы используете набор полученных их БД данных как список (List), то вам надо преобразовать DbSet в List методом ToList